# Using Spring Boot 2 WebClient, in threadsafe / per-request manner, how send diff headers every request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

In Spring Boot 1.5.x, I could use interceptors with `AsyncRestTemplate` to grab headers from an incoming request to a `RestController` endpoint and put them in any `exchange` requests made via the `AsyncRestTemplate`.

I don't see how this can work with the `WebClient`. It looks like if you build a `WebClient` that all its headers, etc are set and unchangeable:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl( "http://blah.com" )
    .defaultHeader( "Authorization", "Bearer ey..." )
    .build();
```

While I can change these using `client.mutate()`, that instantiates a completely new WebClient object. I'd prefer not to have to create a new one on every request. Is there no way to keep a `WebClient` and have per-request headers and other parameters?

It seems like a big waste and poor performance to force creating a new object every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're using here are the default headers that should be sent for all requests sent by this `WebClient` instance. So this is useful for general purpose headers.

You can of course change the request headers on a per-request basis like this:

```
Mono<String> result = this.webClient.get()
      .uri("/greeting")
      .header("Something", "value")
      .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
```

If you wish to have an interceptor-like mechanism to mutate the request before sending it, you can configure the `WebClient` instance with a filter:

```
WebClient
    .builder()
    .filter((request, next) -> {
            // you can mutate the request before sending it
            ClientRequest newRequest = ClientRequest.from(request)
                    .header("Something", "value").build();
            return next.exchange(newRequest);
})
```

Please check out [the Spring Framework documentation about WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client).